# pass protocols to command from file

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, command-line, openssh

Manual run of following command works fine

/jrr/bin/java -Xms14M -Xm14M -Dhttps.protocols=Tv1.2 -Dk.ts.client.protocols=TLSv.2 -jar /gq1/ust/classes/S.jar $(< /pass.txt)

but shell fails
can't read "(< /pass.txt)": no such variable

## !/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh gq1@a732.co.com "/jrr/bin/java -Xms14M -Xm14M -Dhttps.protocols=Tv1.2 -Dk.ts.client.protocols=TLSv.2 -jar /gq1/ust/classes/S.jar $(< /pass.txt);cd /gucq1/gcust;mail -s 'Hello' sam@gm.com < logs.txt"
expect "password"
send "N0\r"
interact
expect eof.

Comment: please do not change question, as is my answer in completly useless. you asked a question about **bash**, then about **expect**, those ar two differents topic. would you kindly rollback to version 5 and ask a new question ?

Comment: My apologies... I will change it to previous version.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
command $(< abc.txt)
```

where

- `$(< )` construct will read file, strip end of line and replace in command line

More information in Bash's manual, chapter [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing *command* and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of  the  command,  with  any
>          trailing newlines deleted.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.  The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

Comment: Need one more help please.. 

Manual run of following command works fine 

/jrr/bin/java -Xms14M -Xm14M -Dhttps.protocols=Tv1.2 -Dk.ts.client.protocols=TLSv.2 -jar /gq1/ust/classes/S.jar $(< /pass.txt)

but shell fails 
can't read "(< /pass.txt)": no such variable

#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh gq1@a732.co.com "/jrr/bin/java -Xms14M -Xm14M -Dhttps.protocols=Tv1.2 -Dk.ts.client.protocols=TLSv.2 -jar /gq1/ust/classes/S.jar $(< /pass.txt);cd /gucq1/gcust;mail -s 'Hello' sam@gm.com < logs.txt"
expect "password"
send "N0\r"
interact
expect eof.